# adding gap to UItableview cells on iphone

Tags: iphone, uitableview

i have lets say 7 cells , now i want one cells to be on top and then lets say after a gap of 200 pixel
i want to show reaming 6 cells together ??

how to do that and is that effective in terms of memory , i was thinking of adding transparent cells 
but i want to know your suggestions

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i did it like this

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 250)];

   // UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 55)];
    //label.text = @"BlaBla";
    [view addSubview:myButton];

    self.tabelView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;

    self.tabelView.tableHeaderView = view;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If that first cell represents a different *thing* than your other cells, and it's always going to be on top of the whole table, give it its own view. Create a view and assign it to the tableView.tableHeaderView, probably on viewDidLoad.

Answer (score -1):

in your UITableViewDelegate type

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if( indexPath.row == 0 )  return height1;

     return height2;
}
```

Comment: no thats not the solution, i want to separate cells what about the gap in between???using that code keep replicating  my data

Comment: well, then try using table sections

Answer (score -1):

I would have 2 sections in a sectioned tableView, the first section with one row, the second with 6 rows. I would add a footer to the first section with a view that is 200 pixels high.

In this case, set row_height to the height you want the gap between sections.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{
                    if (section == 0){
                         UIView *footerView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,  self.tableView.bounds.size.width, row_height)] autorelease];
                         return footerView;
                    }
         return nil;
    }
```